# How to get the particular element from each index using groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to collect only the filename from each index. Let's say I have code like this:

```
List files = new FileNameFinder().getFileNames(importSpec.stgDir, '**')
```

This are the elements that I will get in this list:

```
/***
files[0] = "data/hub/temp/stg/filename.csv"
files[1] = "data/hub/temp/stg/filename.csv"
files[2] = "data/hub/temp/stg/filename.csv"
****/
```

I want only the filenames from each index. Is there any method in groovy which does that, because I didn't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `collect` method of the collection:

```
List files = [
    "data/hub/temp/stg/filename1.csv",
    "data/hub/temp/stg/filename2.csv",
    "data/hub/temp/stg/filename3.csv"
]

List names = files.collect { it.split('/').last() }

names.each {
    println it
}
```

I hope it'll help you.